# Speak to (topic) or speak on (topic)?

Tags: grammar

Here's an example:

> BizComm is miles ahead of industry when it comes to artificial intelligence - a subject **James will speak to** later in the presentation.

I find this phrase jarring. The following seems to flow better:

> BizComm is miles ahead of industry when it comes to artificial intelligence - a subject **James will speak on** later in the presentation.

Thoughts and comments? Is it even grammatically correct?

Comment: Please cite the source.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319652/another-verb-for-speaks-to

Comment: Also related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392331/why-do-so-many-people-speak-to-topics-rather-than-on-or-about-them-is-thi

Comment: @Kris I made it up.

Comment: In the first example, the use of **speak to** would make most sense if James worked for a *competitor* of BizComm that was trying to go after BizComm's market lead. We don't generally **speak to** matters that are going well.  *The mayor will speak to the discovery of high levels of lead in the city's domestic water system.*  That is, "offer comments that show how the city is trying to address concerns about"

Answer (score 2):

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*speak*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speak):

> **1 C(2)** : to address one's remarks
>   // *speak* to the issue

From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/speak):

> 1.7 (**speak to**) Answer (a question) or address (an issue or problem)
>   ‘we should be disappointed if the report did not speak to the issue of literacy’

---

So, it's certainly grammatical. If you speak *to* something it means that you are going to address it—and, generally, it will be a problem.

On the other hand, if you speak *on* something, then you will be talking *about* it, not necessarily presenting an argument for or against it, or raising it as an actual problem that needs to be resolved or discussed.

---

While *speak* ***to*** and *speak* ***on*** do have subtly different meanings, [Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speak%20to%20the%20issue%2C%20speak%20on%20the%20issue&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeak%20to%20the%20issue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspeak%20on%20the%20issue%3B%2Cc0) shows that *speak* ***to*** is more common in print:

[image: speak to or on]

Comment: If you look at British English specifically, the contrast between the two forms is noticeably less; they were neck and neck, until about 2000, and only since then has  "speak on the issue" fallen away.

Comment: What about 'speak to/on the subject ...'?

Comment: **speak on** is more common in print because **speak to** is used more often in *viva-voce* settings, such as when a reporter puts a politician on the spot and asks them to address a particular concern. At least in American English.  The reporter's question doesn't appear in print, only the answer, or snippets taken from it.

Answer (score 1):

To "speak to" an issue or concern is to *address* that concern.  In this sense, "speak to" is a phrasal verb, and the adverb particle ("to") gives the expression a meaning different from its use in an instance where "to" is strictly a preposition, as in "She will speak to the mayor."  To "speak on" a subject is to speak *about* it in a more general sense.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

James will speak to :

is not correct because 'speak to' is used to express 'to whom it is addressed', not the topic.

James will speak on :

is correct.